# C - deconstructing a struct into char array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Why does the code below produces

```
09 17 13 FFFFFF88
```

Where I expect to see

```
09 13 88
```

Code below

```
struct ztest
{
  uint8_t a;
  uint16_t b;
};

struct ztest zt;
char * dd = (char *) &zt;
zt.a = 9;
zt.b = 5000;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(zt); i++) {
   printf("%02X ",dd[i]);
}
```

This is running on openwrt system ar71xx. The aim is to send the char array over a serial line (in case that's relevant).

Comment: `char * dd = (char *) &zt;` ** -->>** `unsigned char * dd = (unsigned char *) &zt;`

Comment: that has fixed the FFFFFF88. Thank you. Now I still have a spurious one as I now get 09 6D 13 88. What is that 6D doing here. Or the 17 above?

Comment: Spurious data is likely padding. You will need to take it into account. Also don't do this for really storing data, this method is OK as a debugging aid but the real storage method is just `fwrite(&zt, ...)`

Comment: `sizeof  zt` is probably 4.  **padding** added an extra (unused) byte.

Comment: Not for storage no. Transmission. Ok padding is my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Whether it's for transmission or storage is irrelevant, if you want to serialise data you should serialise it properly. Just taking the raw bytes like this is not portable, brittle and, in some cases, dangerous...

Comment: What's reason for unsigned? Would you mind explaining it? @wildplasser

Comment: @SeanBurton Indeed. Case in point: MS Word documents from the mid-'90s.

Comment: The reason is sign-extending. see @dasblinkenlight 's answer. The base reason is that printf() is a varargs function, and the values for its arguments are automatically  promoted to *larger* types before passing them . (mostly: int and double)

Comment: For transmission, use proper portable field-by-field serialisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code relies on implementation-defined behavior, so it is not possible to predict what you are going to see without knowing the specifics of the system on which it runs:

- Size of `struct ztest` may include *padding*
- `char` may be signed or unsigned
- Bytes of `uint16_t` may be stored in big-endian or little-endian form

It appears that your system adds one byte of padding to `struct ztest`, uses signed `char`s, and stores `uint16_t` with the most significant byte at a lower address.

The value of `0x17` is "junk" from the padding byte. The value of `0x88` gets sign-extended for printing as a signed `int`, resulting in `0xFFFFFF88` printout.

Answer (score 0):

The structure `ztest` has size 4. It has one unsigned char, one padding byte, and two bytes for the short. So when trying to display `dd[1]` you are actually having an undefined behavior.

Comment: Here the analyzed source code in case you want to check: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/8b143260

Comment: It is very defined. Padding byte with the value which does not matter. Undefined Behaviour means something different

Comment: @4386427 accessing `dd[1]` in the call to printf uses an uninitialised value of size 8. You can check that using tsnippet or valgrind. The reference for undefined behavior can be for instance the 3.4.3 section of the C11 standard.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 if you use the tsnippet analyzer you get an undefined behaviour, if you use valgrind you get "Use of uninitialised value of size 8". This is what i meant by undefined behavior.